# What type of statistical test can be used to compare multiple sets of data

Tags: variability

I have attached a picture of my data plot to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do. The data is pH adjustment of samples, the left most grouping is the pH curve of one set of samples with the adjustment done by different people. The right most grouping is the pH curve of another set of samples with the adjustment done by the same group of people.

My primary curiosity is in determining how different the member curves of each grouping are from each other.

If there is a way to compare the groupings to each other, I would be interested in learning about that as well.

Sorry I can't use more precise statistical language.

[image: Data plots]

Comment: These are functional data analysis problems. Springer-Verlag has a book on this topic. I will supply the reference. The book is titled Functional Data Analysis by Bernard Silverman and James Ramsay.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will try to get that book or at least read on FDA.